# Returning multiple rows in asp:Table from SQL DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

Below is a section of my site where the data is being loaded by a sql query in the code behind, which is listed below as well... My question is how can I duplicate the second **< tr >** in the **< table >** if there are more than one record returned in the code behind query... Any pointers or tips are appreciated...

--.aspx Table
`

```
<h2>Rebate Measures</h2>
<asp:Textbox ID="ProjectID" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
<table border="1">
<tr style="background-color: beige">
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th>Packet #</th>
    <th>EEC Ref #</th>
    <th class="auto-style1">PTR Ref #</th>
    <th>Residential Measure</th>
    <th>PTCS</th>
    <th>PTCS Ducts</th>
    <th>PTCS Comm</th>
    <th>Bus Bar KWh</th>
    <th>Saved KWh</th>
    <th>Msr Life</th>
    <th>BPA Credit Rate</th>
    <th>BPAtoFPUD Reimburse</th>
    <th># of Units</th>
    <th>Unit Type</th>
    <th>Funding Source</th>
    <th>Bid Cost</th>
    <th>Customer Rebate</th>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:#E0E0E0">
    <td>
        <asp:ImageButton Style="float:none; width: 20px; padding: 0; display: inline" ToolTip="Delete" OnClick="Delete_Click" ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="Images/DeletePage.gif" runat="server"></asp:ImageButton>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="ddl" Width="60px" OnTextChanged="PacketNum_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddl" ID="DropDownList2" Width="115px" OnTextChanged="EECNum_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td class="auto-style1">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="100px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" Width="350px" runat="server" Wrap="true" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" MaxLength="3" Columns="1"  runat="server" Width="34px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="61px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Width="59px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Width="45px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Width="45px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Width="30px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Width="78px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" BackColor="LightPink" runat="server" Width="128px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" TextMode="Number" OnTextChanged="PacketNum_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" CssClass="ddl" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="EA" Value="EA"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="SqFt" Value="SqFt"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="LnFt" Value="LnFt"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" CssClass="ddl" OnTextChanged="PacketNum_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="EEI" Value="EEI" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Self" Value="Self"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Delta" Value="Delta"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Width="63px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" Width="93px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

`

--Code Behind Query

```
 string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CARD"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                String sql = "Select * from tbl_Measures_New1 Where Project_ID = @ProjectID and Project_ID like 'R%'";
                    SqlDataAdapter Msrda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
                    Msrda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", ProjectID.Text);
                    DataSet Msrds = new DataSet();
                    Msrda.Fill(Msrds, "Msr");

                    ViewState["SQL"] = sql;
                    ViewState["Msr"] = Msrds;

                    if (Msrds.Tables["Msr"].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DataRow Msrdr = Msrds.Tables["Msr"].Rows[0];
                        AccountSelect.Text = Msrdr["Account_Num"].ToString();
                        OccCode.Text = Msrdr["Occ_Code"].ToString();
                        Measure.Text = Msrdr["Measure"].ToString();
                        Funding.SelectedValue = Msrdr["Funding_Source"].ToString();
                        PacketNum.Text = Msrdr["FPUD_Packet_No"].ToString();
                        EECNum.Text = Msrdr["EEC_Ref_Num"].ToString();
                        PTRNum1.Text = Msrdr["BPA_Ref_Num"].ToString();
                        VendorList.SelectedValue = Msrdr["Vendor_ID"].ToString();
                        SecVendorList.SelectedValue = Msrdr["Secondary_Vendor_ID"].ToString();
                        BidCost.Text = "$" + Msrdr["Measure_Cost"].ToString().Replace(".0000", ".00");
                        CustomerRebate.Text = "$" + Msrdr["Customer_Rebate"].ToString().Replace(".0000", ".00");
                        SavedKWh.Text = Msrdr["Saved_Kwh"].ToString();
                        Busbar.Text = Msrdr["BusBar_Kwh"].ToString();
                        BPACredit.Text = "$" + Msrdr["BPA_Credit"].ToString().Replace(".0000", ".00");
                        BPAReimburse.Text = "$" + Msrdr["BPA-FPUD_Reimburse"].ToString().Replace(".0000", ".00");
                        Units.Text = Msrdr["Measure_Units"].ToString();
                        if (Units.Text != "")
                        {
                            Units.Text = Msrdr["Measure_Units"].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Units.Text = "1";
                        }
                        UnitType.SelectedValue = Msrdr["Unit_Type"].ToString();
                        MsrLife.Text = Msrdr["Measure_Life"].ToString();
                        PTCS.Text = Msrdr["PTCS"].ToString();
                        Ducts.Text = Msrdr["PTCS_Ducts"].ToString();
                        Comm.Text = Msrdr["PTCS_Comm"].ToString();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.  Look into the Repeater control if you want to use a table like this, or look into using a GridView and binding your result set to that.  (It is possible to have a dropdowns and textboxes inside of a GridView.)

Also, make sure your code validates ProjectID.Text to avoid any potential SQL injection issues!